AZ run-command invoke confusion
Included below is the end of a script that sets up an azure vm, then uses "AZ run-command invoke" to pass a script to the vm that would set up a site in docker.
Does anyone know why this command:
az vm run-command invoke --command-id RunShellScript --name $vmName --resource-group    $resourceGroupName --scripts "@./kickstart.sh"

Returns this result?
{
  "value": [
    {
      "code": "ProvisioningState/succeeded",
      "displayStatus": "Provisioning succeeded",
      "level": "Info",
      "message": "Enable succeeded: \n[stdout]\nReading package lists...\nBuilding dependency tree...\nReading state information...\n\nNo apt package \"docker\", but there is a snap with that name.\nTry \"snap install docker\"\n\n\n[stderr]\n\nWARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.\n\nE: Unable to locate package docker\n/var/lib/waagent/run-command/download/0/script.sh: line 3: docker: command not found\n",
      "time": null
    }
  ]
}

And fails to stand up the site?
I think I'm close here...
I tried to run an azure command with an expected outcome and got a message that confuses me.

Could you please share the script of kickstart.sh that you are trying to run inside the VM?

 "Enable succeeded:  Unable to locate package docker\n/var/lib/waagent/run-command/download/0/script.sh: line 3: docker: command not found\n"

The error message indicates that there is no apt package named docker available in the Ubuntu package repository, but there is a snap package available

To resolve the issue, you can install Docker with snap using the command snap install docker or with apt using sudo apt-get install docker.io
kickstart.sh
    #!/bin/bash
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io -y
    sudo docker version

                         OR

kickstart.sh
 #!/bin/bash
sudo snap install docker

az vm run-command invoke --command-id RunShellScript --name "Venkat-LinuxVM" --resource-group "Venkat" --scripts "@./kickstart.sh"

Output:

Docker has been installed after executing the above command.

